# I want to use Mathematica Reference pages for an Appendix in a LaTeX report

Tags: latex, copy-as

I want to put the aforementioned information in an appendix(obviously I will Cite it) of a LaTeX report, however I get a variety of Errors when I attempt to do so.

I was trying the [Module](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) page, I've opened it in mathematica and tried copying certain information in LaTeX form and saving it as a LaTeX file but it doesn't work. I've also Tried `?Module` in Mathematica and I have the same Issues.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Print it to PDF.  Use the appropriate page size during printing, and in File -> Printing settings adjust the header and footer as necessary.  Insert the PDF pages directly into your document.  The `pdfpages` LaTeX package should make this possible.